# What is the order of overwrite Maven properties in pom.xml and settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven

today I observed that the maven proprties defined in `settings.xml` overwrite the one in `pom.xml`.

Because it is only a observation, I am not sure if this is totally correct. So I am looked for the reference or some article but I find no concrete statement about the behaviour of overwriting properties defined with the same name in `settings.xml` and `pom.xml`.

Maybe someone can provide a link to the reference part (that I may overlooked) or the a reliable article/blog?

Comment: Have you a profile with the same id or with different id's ?

Comment: The properties in the POM are without any profile; the properies in the settings.xml are located in an profile with an id that is used no where else.

Comment: But if your properties have the same name either in pom as well as in the settings.xml so they will be overwritten by the values of them which are coming from the settings.xml file. Otherwise it would not be possible to overwrite properties by a profile.

Comment: @khmarbaise correct - that was the observed behaviour. And I only wanted to know where this behaviour is defined/descriped. -- The link in your answer, as well as the cite was what I was looking for.

Comment: @khmarbaise: the scenario is: I have a project, and need to change some values that are specific for the developer stations, but I do not want to have a single profile for each single developer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles) in my opinion it is clear which one has precedence over the other (excerpt of the docs):

> If a profile is active from settings, its values will override any
>   equivalently ID'd profiles in a POM or profiles.xml file.

The profiles.xml does not exist anymore in Maven 3 only in Maven 2.2.1 it is supported but shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 8):

I think properties with equal names are overridden in next sequence (from highest to lowest context):

- Global
- Profile descriptor
- Per project
- Per user

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Hence, `pom.xml` properties (per project) are overridden by `settings.xml` (per user) properties with equal names.

Comment: Any idea what `-D` counts as?

Comment: @Christian this seems to have the maximum priority and overrides everything, i.e. should come last in this list.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested it on my maven 3.3.9.

First of all, properties are always defined in profiles, if we are talking about settings.xml.
Properties from global settings XML have the highest priority and will override both user `settings.xml` and a specific `pom.xml`, **UNLESS** there is a name collision between profiles.

If it's the case, that is there is a **profile with the same id** in global, user settings, as well as pom.xml, user/local settings.xml is the boss.
Even if a property in `pom.xml` doesn't sit inside a profile, user/local `settings.xml` property from an active profile with the same name will beat it. 
Incidentally, global `settings.xml` will also beat pom.xml property without a profile.

***As a side note:***
For `<repositories>` and `<mirrors>` the logic is slightly different:

- User/local settings have higher priority than global for `<mirrors>`.
- However, for `<repositories>`: pom - highest, then - local, then - global.

Comment: The way Maven sets the precedence is so confusing and inconsistent.